# Cannot resolve context method

Tags: java, android, database

I'm trying to use database in my app and have created an helper class with onCreate and onUpgrade method and an constructor. Then in another class I try to create an object of my helper class with getContext() as they do on the android development documentation. But I get an error saying "cannot resolve method getContext()". I have googled and try like getApplicationContext and that doesn't work. This in the argument doesn't work either. Here is the class I try to write it:

```
public class SearchResultItem {

DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());

@JsonKey("Title") // You need to write this so the jsonparser knows which value to get
private String mTitle;

@JsonKey("Year")
private String mYear;

@JsonKey("imdbID")
private String mImdbId;

@JsonKey("Type")
private String mType;

public String getTitle()
{
    return mTitle;
}

public String getYear()
{
    return mYear;
}

public String getImdbId()
{
    return mImdbId;
}

public String getType()
{
    return mType;
}
```

}

And my DbHelper class looks like this if it's needed:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movies.db";

//Table name
private static final String MOVIE_TABLE = "movies";

//Column names
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
private static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";
private static final String COLUMN_PLOT = "plot";

Context context;
public DbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) { // Called when the database is created for the first time
    final String SQL_MOVIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MOVIE_TABLE + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            COLUMN_YEAR + " REAL," + COLUMN_PLOT + " TEXT" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_MOVIE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) { // Called when the database needs to be upgraded/changed or dropped
    //Drop older table if it exists
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MOVIE_TABLE);

    //Create table again
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

private boolean haveNetworkConnection()
{
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for(NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
    {
        if(ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        {
            if(ni.isConnected())
            {
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
            }
        }

        if(ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        {
            if(ni.isConnected())
            {
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Anyone have any clues on how I can solve this?

Comment: Are you using dbHelper in SearchResultItem ?If not you can comment that out

Comment: @playmaker420 Yes, that's what I want to do. Why should I comment it out?

Comment: Didnt see any usage of dbHelper  in SearchResultItem class other than that line.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you want to use your dbHelper object in a pojo class?

Comment: If you want to initialize you dbHelper  in SearchResultItem, Create a constructor in SearchResultItem  and pass the activity context to the constructor and move your dbHelper initialization inside the constructor.It should work.

Comment: @playmaker420 I have an app right now which you can search for movies, you enter movie title and press search and it gives you the title and year of the movies in a listview, and it takes the information from an API. But now I want to fix so it saves the previous state, for example if you searched a movie and then close the internet on your phone and open it again, then it should be the same state. So I created an DbHelper class which is needed, but then I wasn't sure where to write the methods that add the information to the database. I was just guessing in SearchResultItem

Comment: DbHelper dbHelper;

     public SearchResultItem(Context context)
     {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
     } This gave me no errors, hope it works if I continue and write the code here in this class now.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
  context = getApplicationContext();
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it didn't work, I got the same error in that class if I tried context = getApplicationContext() and context = getContext().

Comment: Didn't work, and it says "super" must be the first in the constructor so we can't do that.

Comment: The one from playmaker420.